# Pointer and address in C

Tags: c, pointers, variables, pointer-address

My teacher has these question on his lecture powerpoint but no answer. Can someone help. new to c.

```
If a is an int variable, is it always true that *&a == a ?
If p is an int* variable, is it always true that p == &*p ?
Is it ever meaningful to say **p ?
Is it ever meaningful to say &&a ?
After assigning a = 2 and p = &a, how much is *p**p ?
If furthermore q = &p, how much is **q**p***q ?
```

Finally, how much is a/*p ?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, yes, 4, ffs.

Comment: I remember the prof saying no for the first one. So cant trust u

Comment: Well, then ask the prof, if you don't trust. :D

Comment: @spatil then why bother asking if you'll shoot people down?

Comment: @NickA I mean its not that im shooting him down. I just need an explanation like the guy gave me down there...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a "do my homework" site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If a is an int variable, is it always true that *&a == a ?

It *should* be, but I can't find a definitive statement to that effect.

> If p is an int* variable, is it always true that p == &*p ?

Yes - in that case, neither the `&` nor `*` operators are actually evaluated.  See the [online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) of the C 2011 standard, §
6.5.3.2 ¶ 3.

> Is it ever meaningful to say **p ?

Yes.  Multiple indirection shows up all over the place.  You can have pointers to pointers, pointers to pointers to pointers, pointers to arrays of pointers, pointers to functions returning pointers to arrays of pointers to pointers to pointers, etc.

> Is it ever meaningful to say &&a ?

No. The result of `&a` is not an lvalue, so you cannot apply the `&` operator to it.  To put it another way, what's the address of an address?

> After assigning a = 2 and p = &a, how much is *p**p ?

*Should* be the same as `a * a`, although be aware that C's tokenizing algorithm is "greedy", so you *really* want to separate terms and operators with whitespace.

> If furthermore q = &p, how much is **q**p***q ?

Again, it *should* be the same as `a * a * a`, and again, be aware of how C tokenizes expressions.

Comment: Would **p ever be meaningful given that p points to an int? Before you could dereference it, you would need to case *p from an int to a pointer? Am I missing something?

Comment: @ScottK p only points to an integer in the prior and former questions, in that specific question it could be referring to any situations such as when p is a pointer to a pointer rather than pointer to an integer. As it stands the questions are quite ambiguous.

Comment: @ScottK: I admit I answered the wrong question there - if `p` is declared as `int *p`, then no, `**p` would not be meaningful.  The *result* of `&p` would have type `int **`, though.